Stop replaying logs played via -11! when a criteria is satisfied in KDB
I have customized my .z.ps function to log some specific lines upon replaying a file. What I want to do is stop replaying the logs as soon as my criteria is satisfied. Is it possible to do it ?
.z.ps{ /customized to meet some criteria and log some info }
{ -11! hsym x } each `:/home/mydir

How can i make sure that if my criteria is satisfied the log replaying via -11! is stopped ?
Note that i do not want to take risk of playing partial logs like first 1K or 10K or 100K. My logs are in 100s of GB, so i am looking to fast the overall process by extracting info i need without replaying entire log file.

You can do this by not running value on the remaining records after your criteria is satisfied. You can't stop the full -11! from completing if you've initiated it. You would do something like:
.z.ps:{if[criteria_not_yet_met;value x]}

Similar to this example in the docs: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/logging/#replay-part-of-a-file
That example is slightly different - do nothing until criteria met - but your situation is similar.
Another approach is for example if your -11! is replaying a bunch of upd commands then you could override upd to do nothing after your criteria is satisfied.
.z.ps:{if[criteria_satisfied;`upd set{y;()}];value x}

You might need to set the upd back to normal after you're done.
